# Skip remainder of line with fscanf in C

Tags: c, scanf

I'm reading in a file and after reading in a number, I want to skip to remaining part of that line. An example of a file is this

```
2 This part should be skipped
10 and also this should be skipped
other part of the file
```

At the moment I solve this by using this loop:

```
char c = '\0';
while(c!='\n') fscanf(f, "%c", &c);
```

I was however wondering whether there isn't a better way of doing this. I tried this, but for some reason it isn't working:

```
fscanf(f, "%*[^\n]%*c");
```

I would have expected this to read everything up to the new line and then also read the new line. I don't need the content, so I use the * operator. However, when I use this command nothing happens. The cursor isn't moved.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suggest you to use [**fgets()**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gets.3.html) and then **[sscanf()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html)** to read the number. scanf() function is prone to errors and you can quite easily get the format string wrong which may seem to work for most cases and fail unexpectedly for some cases when you find it doesn't handle some specific input formats.

A quick search for **[scanf() problems](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=scanf%28%29%20problems)** on SO would show how often people get it wrong and run into problems when using scanf().

Instead fgets() + sscanf() gives would give you better control and you know for sure you have read one line and you can process the line you read to read integer out it:

```
char line[1024];


while(fgets(line, sizeof line, fp) ) {

   if( sscanf(line, "%d", &num) == 1 ) 
   {
    /* number found at the beginning */
   }
   else
   {
    /* Any message you want to show if number not found and 
     move on the next line */
   }
}
```

You may want to change how you read `num` from `line` depending on the format of lines in the file. But in your case, it seems the integer is either located at first or not present at all. So the above will work fine.

Comment: I totally agree.  However, just using `fgets` and `sscanf` isn't sufficient if the line is longer than what the `fgets` call consumes and if nvcleemp wants to discard the unread portion of the line.

Comment: The format of the file is a bit more complicated. I had just simplified it for this question. But I can work for this. I'll have to see how I should handle long lines, but I think I can restrict myself to lines of length shorter than 1024.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    FILE *f = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    int n, stat;
    do{
        if(1==(stat=fscanf(f, "%d", &n))){
            printf("n=%d\n", n);
        }
    }while(EOF!=fscanf(f, "%*[^\n]"));
    fclose(f);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Reviewed C11 7.21.6.2.8, "Input white-space characters (as specified by the isspace function) are skipped, unless the specification includes a [, c, or n specifier."  The necessity still eludes me as `%d` functions just like ` %d`.  Also tried various inputs and received the same `fscanf()` return.  Your thoughts as to how the space is used?

Comment: @chux What you say is correct. I seems to have misunderstood. Thanks For Stopping to point out.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to parse the /proc/self/maps file, but only wanted the first 2 columns (start and end of address range). This worked fine with Linux gcc.

scanf("%llx-%llx %*[^\n]\n", &i, &e);

The trick was "%*[^\n]\n" which means skip a sequence of anything except the end of line, then skip the end of line.